# Alternatives to evernote?

Tags: evernote

this is my first question.

I'm looking for an evernote type application for ubuntu. Basically a way to "cloud store" terminal recipes (like a blog reminder) that I can access later either in ubuntu or in my android smartphone.

Any help or recomendations would be much appreciated

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Evernote itself? An alternative I've fiddled with is the combination. A review ofthis method can be found [here](http://blog.eogn.com/eastmans_online_genealogy/2010/11/rednotebook-a-personal-diary-and-quick-journal.html). A comparison of Evernote vs RedNotebook can be found [here](http://blog.eogn.com/eastmans_online_genealogy/2010/11/rednotebook-versus-evernote.html). The Rednotebook project page is avaliable [here](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I personally really enjoy nitro notes, works well for me. On my Ubuntu machines I have it installed, I have it in Chromium portable from the Chrome store, and I have NitroDroid on my Galaxy S3 & N7. It all sync using Ubuntu One, or Drop Box if you prefer.